# How to add header/footer in chartsheet using Openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I tried to add a footer and a header to the chartsheet I made, but when I check the print settings its not there. There's no errors that pop-up either.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import ScatterChart, Reference, Series

wb = Workbook()
cs = wb.create_chartsheet()

cs.oddHeader.text = "Header"
cs.oddFooter.text = "Footer"
wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

Comment: These two imports will not do anything, especially nothing that is related to the error you describe.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to help others help you.

Comment: I pressed enter by accident

Comment: Does it work on a normal worksheet (as opposed to a chartsheet)?

Comment: Yes, when I did this for a worksheet, it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I later found out that openpyxl didn't support this feature, at least when I was using this, so I replaced it with xlsxwriter.